# Troubleshoot with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking over a JS and HTML for my friend, because it doesn't work, and I have spent 5 hours on it, and I can't stil find the error...

When you test the code in jsfiddle, try to click on "Bountie", it should take HP from you, but it doesn't, it does nothing...

Im sorry for the long code.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gfvtvq9f/6/)

```
/*
Variables
Started at 10:57 1/2-16
Finished at unknown

*/

//Level variables
var level = 1;
var gon = 0;
var xp = 0;
var sp = 3;

//Item variables
var items = 0;
var key = 0;
var gem = 0;
var stone = 0;

//Token system
var token = 0;
var heatf = 0;
var heltf = 0;

//Quest system
var bountieqp = 0;
var mapqp = 10;
var hellqp = 10;
var heavenqp = 10;
var underworldqp = 10;

//Quest tracker
var bountieqtracker = 0;
var mapqtracker = 0;
var hellqtracker = 0;
var heavenqtracker = 0;
var underworldqtracker = 0;

//Predium varables
var giftbox = 1;

//Combats variables
var str = 0;
var dex = 0;
var intt = 0;
var armor = 4;
var dmg = 5;
var hp = 300;
var hpren = 3;
var mana = 60;
var manaren = 1;

//Addon variables
var xpbonus = 1;
var xponkill = 0;
var mf = 1;
var souls = 0;

//Prestige system
var prelevel = 1;
var ppiece = 0;

//Map tracker variables
var bountietracker = 0;
var maptracker = 0;
var gmaptracker = 0;
var helltracker = 0;
var heaventracker = 0;
var underworldtracker = 0;

//Quest system updates
document.getElementById('hellqp').innerHTML = hellqp;
document.getElementById('heavenqp').innerHTML = heavenqp;
document.getElementById('bountieqp').innerHTML = bountieqp;
document.getElementById('mapqp').innerHTML = mapqp;
document.getElementById('underworldqp').innerHTML = underworldqp;

//Tracker system updates
document.getElementById('maptracker').innerHTML = maptracker;
document.getElementById('underworldtracker').innerHTML = underworldtracker;
document.getElementById('gmaptracker').innerHTML = gmaptracker;
document.getElementById('bountietracker').innerHTML = bountietracker;
document.getElementById('helltracker').innerHTML = helltracker;
document.getElementById('heaventracker').innerHTML = heaventracker;

//Quest tracker system updates
document.getElementById('mapqtracker').innerHTML = mapqtracker;
document.getElementById('underworldqtracker').innerHTML = underworldqtracker;
document.getElementById('bountieqtracker').innerHTML = bountieqtracker;
document.getElementById('hellqtracker').innerHTML = hellqtracker;
document.getElementById('heavenqtracker').innerHTML = heavenqtracker;

//Stats system updates
document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = sp;
document.getElementById('dex').innerHTML = dex;
document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = str;
document.getElementById('intt').innerHTML = intt;
document.getElementById('dmg').innerHTML = dmg;
document.getElementById('hp').innerHTML = hp;
document.getElementById('mana').innerHTML = mana;
document.getElementById('armor').innerHTML = armor;
document.getElementById('hpren').innerHTML = hpren;
document.getElementById('manaren').innerHTML = manaren;

//Addon system updates
document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
document.getElementById('souls').innerHTML = souls;
document.getElementById('xponkill').innerHTML = xponkill;
document.getElementById('xpbonus').innerHTML = xpbonus;
document.getElementById('mf').innerHTML = mf;

//Items system updates
document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = key;
document.getElementById('stone').innerHTML = stone;
document.getElementById('gem').innerHTML = gem;
document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = items;
document.getElementById('token').innerHTML = token;
document.getElementById('heatf').innerHTML = heatf;
document.getElementById('heltf').innerHTML = heltf;

//Level system updates
document.getElementById('level').innerHTML = level;
document.getElementById('gon').innerHTML = gon;
document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;

/*
Test selection
*/



/*
Predium Addons
Started at 14:10 1/2-16
Finished at
*/

function openBox() {
    var boxrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var gembrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var itemsbrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var keybrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var stonebrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var bountieqpbrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var mapqpbrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var hellqpbrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var heavenqpbrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var underworldqpbrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var heltfrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var heabrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var xpbrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500000 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (boxrand == 1) {
        gem = gem + gembrand;
        document.getElementById('gem').innerHTML = gem;
    } else if (boxrand == 2) {
        items = items + itemsbrand;
        document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = items;
    }else if (boxrand == 3) {
        key = key + keybrand;
        document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = key;
    }else if (boxrand == 4) {
        stone = stone + stonebrand;
        document.getElementById('stone').innerHTML = stone;
    }else if (boxrand == 5) {
        bountieqp = bountieqp + bountieqpbrand;
        document.getElementById('bountieqp').innerHTML = bountieqp;
    }else if (boxrand == 6) {
        mapqp = mapqp + mapqpbrand;
        document.getElementById('mapqp').innerHTML = mapqp;
    }else if (boxrand == 7) {
        hellqp = hellqp + hellqpbrand;
        document.getElementById('hellqp').innerHTML = hellqp;
    } else if (boxrand == 8) {
        heavenqp = heavenqp + heavenqpbrand;
        document.getElementById('heavenqp').innerHTML = heavenqp;
    } else if (boxrand == 9) {
        underworldqp = underworldqp + underworldqpbrand;
        document.getElementById('underworldqp').innerHTML = underworldqp;
    } else if(boxrand == 10) {
        heltf = heltf + heltfbrand;
        document.getElementById('heltf').innerHTML = heltf;
    } else if(boxrand == 11) {
        heatf = heatf + heatfbrand;
        document.getElementById('heatf').innerHTML = heatf;
    } else if(boxrand == 12) {
        xp = xp + xpbrand;
        document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
    } else if (boxrand == 13) {
        ppiece = ppiece + ppiecebrand;
        document.getElementById('ppiece').innerHTML = ppiece;
    }
}

function gbChecker() {
    if (giftbox >= 1) {
        openBox();
        giftbox = giftbox - 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    } else {
        alert('You dont have a Mystery Box!');
    }
}

/*
Level 
Started at 11:46 1/2-16
Finished at
*/

function levelUp() {
    var levelCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.1,level));
    if (xp >= levelCost){                                  
        level = level + 1;
        xp = xp - levelCost;                        
        sp = sp + 3;                              
        document.getElementById('level').innerHTML = level;  
        document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp; 
        document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = sp;  
    }
    var nextlevelCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.1,level));      
    document.getElementById('levelCost').innerHTML = nextlevelCost; 
}

function gonUp() {
    var gonCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.1,gon));    
    if (xp >= gonCost) {                                   
        gon = gon + 1;                                   
        xp = xp - gonCost;
        sp = sp + 1;                                  
        document.getElementById('gon').innerHTML = gon; 
        document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;  
        document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = sp;  
    }
    var nextgonCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.1,gon));       
    document.getElementById('gonCost').innerHTML = nextgonCost;  
}

function levelChecker() {
    if (level == 120) {
        gonUp();
    } else {
        levelUp();
    }
}

/*
Addon Makers
Started at 11:34 1/2-16
Finished at 12:42 1/2-16
*/

function pp256Maker() {
    var pp256rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (pp256rand == 1) {
        ppiece = ppiece + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('ppiece').innerHTML = ppiece;
    }
}

function gb256Maker() {
    var gb256rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gb256rand == 1) {
        giftbox = giftbox + 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    }
}

function pp128Maker() {
    var pp128rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (128 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (pp128rand == 1) {
        ppiece = ppiece + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('ppiece').innerHTML = ppiece;
    }
}

function gb128Maker() {
    var gb128rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (128 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gb128rand == 1) {
        giftbox = giftbox + 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    }
}

function pp25Maker() {
    var pp25rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (pp25rand == 1) {
        ppiece = ppiece + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('ppiece').innerHTML = ppiece;
    }
}

function gb64Maker() {
    var gb64rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (64 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gb64rand == 1) {
        giftbox = giftbox + 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    }
}

function pp17Maker() {
    var pp17rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (pp17rand == 1) {
        ppiece = ppiece + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('ppiece').innerHTML = ppiece;
    }
}

function gb32Maker() {
    var gb32rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (32 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gb32rand == 1) {
        giftbox = giftbox + 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    }
}

function pp5Maker() {
    var pp5rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (pp5rand == 1) {
        ppiece = ppiece + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('ppiece').innerHTML = ppiece;
    }
}

function gb10Maker() {
    var gb10rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gb10rand == 1) {
        giftbox = giftbox + 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    }
}

function gb16Maker() {
    var gb16rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (16 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gb16rand == 1) {
        giftbox = giftbox + 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    }
}

function gb5Maker() {
    var gb5rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gb5rand == 1) {
        giftbox = giftbox + 1;
        document.getElementById('giftbox').innerHTML = giftbox;
    }
}

/*
Quest Makers
Started at 12:43 1/2-16
Finished at 12:47 1/2-16
*/

function bountieqpMaker() {
    var bountieqprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (bountieqprand == 1) {
        bountieqp = bountieqp + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('bountieqp').innerHTML = bountieqp;
    }
}

function mapqpMaker() {
    var mapqprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (mapqprand == 1) {
        map = map + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('mapqp').innerHTML = mapqp;
    }
}

function hellqpMaker() {
    var bountieqprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (hellqprand == 1) {
        hell = hell + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('hellqp').innerHTML = hellqp;
    }
}

function heavenqpMaker() {
    var heavenqprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (heavenqprand == 1) {
        heavenqp = heavenqp + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('heavenqp').innerHTML = heavenqp;
    }
}

function underworldqpMaker() {
    var underworldqprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (underworldqprand == 1) {
        underworldqp = underworldqp + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('underworldqp').innerHTML = underworldqp;
    }
}

/*
Req items Maker
Started at 12:44 1/2-16
Finished at 13:17 1/2-16
*/

function keyMaker() {
    var keyrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (keyrand == 1) {
        key = key + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = key;
    }
}

function stoneMaker(){
    var stonerand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (stonerand == 1) {
        stone = stone + (1 * mf);
        document.getElementById('stone').innerHTML = stone;
    }
}

/*
Quest completing
Started at 13:17 1/2-16
Finished at 13:45 1/2-16
*/

function bouqChecker(){
    if (bountieqp >= 10) {
        bouQuest();
    } else {
        alert('You dont have 10 Bountie quest pieces!. You only have ' + bountieqp + '!');
    }
}

function mapqChecker(){
    if (mapqp >= 10) {
        mapQuest();
    } else {
        alert('You dont have 10 Map quest pieces!. You only have ' + mapqp + '!');
    }
}

function hellqChecker(){
    if (hellqp >= 10) {
        hellQuest();
    } else {
        alert('You dont have 10 Hell quest pieces!. You only have ' + hellqp + '!');
    }
}

function heavenqChecker(){
    if(heavenqp >= 10){
        heavenQuest();
    }else{
        alert('You dont have 10 Heaven quest pieces!. You only have ' + heavenqp + '!');
    }
}

function underworldqChecker(){
    if(underworldqp >= 10){
        underworldQuest();
    }else{
        alert('You dont have 10 Underworld quest pieces!. You only have ' + underworldqp + '!');
    }
}

function bouQuest(){
    var bouqxprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 200 + 200)) + 1;
    xp = xp + ((bouqxprand * xpbonus) * prelevel);
    bountieqp = bountieqp - 10;
    gb128Maker();
    document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
    document.getElementById('bountieqp').innerHTML = bountieqp; 
}

function mapQuest(){
    var mapqxprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4500 - 850 + 850)) + 1;
    xp = xp + ((mapqxprand * xpbonus) * prelevel);
    mapqp = mapqp - 10;
    gb64Maker();
    document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
    document.getElementById('mapqp').innerHTML = mapqp; 
}

function hellQuest(){
    var hellqxprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (250000 - 50000 + 50000)) + 1;
    xp = xp + ((hellqxprand * xpbonus) * prelevel);
    hellqp = hellqp - 10;
    gb16Maker();
    document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
    document.getElementById('hellqp').innerHTML = hellqp; 
}

function heavenQuest(){
    var heavenqxprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (250000 - 50000 + 50000)) + 1;
    xp = xp + ((heavenqxprand * xpbonus) * prelevel);
    heavenqp = heavenqp - 10;
    gb16Maker();
    document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
    document.getElementById('heavenqp').innerHTML = heavenqp; 
}

function underworldQuest(){
    var underworldqxprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1250000 - 500000 + 500000)) + 1;
    xp = xp + ((underworldqxprand * xpbonus) * prelevel);
    underworldqp = underworldqp - 10;
    gb5Maker();
    document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
    document.getElementById('underworldqp').innerHTML = underworldqp;
}

/*
Bountie Map
Started at 11:27 1/2-16
Finished at 13:18 1/2-16
*/

function doBountie() {
    var bountieCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.006,bountietracker));
    var bouxprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 20 + 20)) + 1;
    var bouitemrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (dmg + armor >= bountieCost) {
        hp = hp - 1;
        xp = xp + (((bouxprand + xponkill) * xpbonus) * prelevel);
        items = items + (bouitemrand * mf);
        bountietracker = bountietracker + 1;
        keyMaker();
        bountieqpMaker();
        pp256Maker();
        gb256Maker();
        document.getElementById('hp').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('hp2').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
        document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = items;
    } else if (hp >= bountieCost) {
        hp = hp - (bountieCost - (armor + dmg));
        xp = xp + (((bouxprand + xponkill) * xpbonus) * prelevel);
        items = items + (bouitemrand* mf);
        bountietracker = bountietracker + 1;
        keyMaker();
        bountieqpMaker();
        pp256Maker();
        gb256Maker();
        document.getElementById('hp').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
        document.getElementById('hp2').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = items;
    }else{
        alert('You dont have enough HP to complete a bountie. Bountie costs ' + bountieCost + ' and you only have ' + hp + '!');
    }
    var nextbountieCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.006,bountietracker));
    document.getElementById('bountieCost').innerHTML = nextbountieCost;
}

/*
Map Map
Started at 12:37 1/2-16
Finished at 
*/

function doMap(){
    var mapCost = Math.floor(300 * Math.pow(1.006,maptracker));
    var mapxprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (850 - 200 + 200)) + 1;
    var mapitemrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 4 + 4)) + 1;
    if(dmg + armor >= mapCost){
        hp = hp - 1;
        xp = xp + (((mapxprand + xponkill) * xpbonus) * prelevel);
        items = items + (mapitemrand * mf);
        keyMaker();
        gb128Maker();
        mapqpMaker();
        document.getElementById('hp').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
        document.getElementById('hp2').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = items;
    }else if(hp >= mapCost){
        hp = hp - (mapCost - (armor + dmg));
        xp = xp + (((mapxprand + xponkill) * xpbonus) * prelevel);
        items = items + (mapitemrand * mf);
        keyMaker();
        gb128Maker();
        mapqpMaker();
        document.getElementById('hp').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('xp').innerHTML = xp;
        document.getElementById('hp2').innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = items;
    }else if(hp =< mapCost){
        alert('You dont have enough HP to complete a Map. Map costs ' + mapCost + ' and you only have ' + hp + '!');
    }else{
        alert('You dont have a key to open a Map!');
    }
    var nextmapCost = Math.floor(300 * Math.pow(1.006,maptracker));
    document.getElementById('mapCost').innerHTML = nextmapCost;
}
```

Comment: You could use the console of your browser, it show the line of your errors

Answer (score -1):

When I click the **bountie** button, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: levelChecker is not defined`.

Also, on Line #582

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

`if(hp =< mapCost)` should be `if(hp <= mapCost)`

It looks like there are a few Javascript errors in your script. I recommend using Google Chrome's Inspection tool for stepping through your Javascript, using breakpoints to see the data and errors.